# Models fitting to different data but input is the same

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, metafor

I am currently running candidates for a meta-analysis using the rma.mv function in metafor. I have tried running models, comparing by AIC, and then averaging using the model.avg approach in the MuMIn package. However, I continue to get an error that indicates my candidate models are fit to different data -- but the dataframe I input is the same for all three models. What is happening here?

The only number I notice that seems to change is the df in the Test for heterogeneity -- what would be causing this change and these models be fit to different data?

The full model I am trying to fit is:

```
full_moda<-rma.mv(yi=yi, V=vi, 
                 mods = ~ I(flux_range-mean(flux_range))*I(mean_temp_constant-mean(mean_temp_constant))*experiment_type
                 +I(secondary_temp - mean(secondary_temp))
                 +duration_standard 
                 +exp_age*experiment_type
                 +size*experiment_type
                 +ecosystem*experiment_type
                 +trait_directionality*experiment_type
                 +sqrt(vi),
                 random = list( ~1 | phylo, ~1 | study_id, ~1 | response_id),
                 R = list(phylo=cor), test="t",
                 method="REML", data=dat_ES_final_2)
```

I have 1703 effect sizes going into this model

And I have been trying to do model selection with different combinations of the moderators to ensure that I am chosing the best model. I have tried using model selection with the glmulti package but it takes days for the task to run, so I have not done that recently. The error I get for every combination of model I run is "error: models are not fitted to the same data". I have cleaned by dataset to ensure there are no NA's so I am really confused about where it would be dropped effect sizes?

Comment: Without more detail this is impossible to answer. My initial guess would be you are fitting models using different variables and they have different amounts of missing data but unless you tell us what models you fitted and what output you got we are in the dark.

Comment: See also: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:model_selection_with_glmulti_and_mumin

Comment: i have updated the post above with the full model I am starting with and then taking different combinations of moderators out

Comment: Can you simplify your code by doing the transforms, creating the dummies and moderators outside of the function call? It's very hard to read.  What's the code that gives you the error?

Comment: I get no warning when I run this code, only when I got average across different candidate models with different combinations of these moderators. That is when got an error indicating that the models were being fit to different data